# Can anyone identify this bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I don't know much about bikes, but I've tried searching around and haven't been able to identify the bike I am currently riding. I know the brand and some specifications but I can't find anything else.

I received this bike a few years ago from a family friend, and it seems slightly old, but definitely not from anytime before the 21st century.

Here are a list of the decals and things written on it:

"Mongoose" (All over it, assuming this is the brand.)

"Raging Element" (On the part connecting the frame to the front tire)

"Maneuver" (On the frame near the handlebars)

"Tubing Aluminum", "Designed in America, Made in China" (On frame)

"Unified Suspension", "21 Speed" (Connecting Frame to back wheel)

"750 (lbs/in)" (On shock absorber)

"TQ One" (On small part near chain)

"PacificCycle", "Support: 800-626-2811", "Model: R4718Z", "Date: FSD02JG" (On sticker, I think this is important but I couldn't find any info on it)

Here are some pictures:
[image]

[image]

https://imgur.com/ug0BQij | https://imgur.com/NqKHMgF

Thank you for helping!
Also, if you are able to find something like a search engine for the model number and such, I am happy to do the searching, I just couldn't find anything. I am also happy to provide any other information you might need that I could get from it. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried calling the telephone number?

Comment: I googled the phone number and found this customerservice@pacific-cycle.com

Comment: Yeah, a pretty standard low-end Mongoose.  I've rehabbed a few.  Decent quality and quite durable for what it is -- the problems I've seen were mainly from abuse or leaving out in the rain.

Answer (score 6):

It's a Mongoose Manuever... late 90's early 2000's if i had to guess. Basically a Walmart or department store bicycle shaped object. There should be a serial number, probably beneath the crank. Pacific Cycles is who bought that division of mongoose which is sold in big box stores.

If you want to know more you could contact Pacific Cycles with the model number and serial number to find out the year, or look them up on google. There are resource sites that help identify the numbers and letters meaning in the model and date codes. Complete guess but i would say a 2002 based on the 02 in the date code.

You have all the information you need to identify it, seems pretty cut and dry.

Bottom line it is not an expensive bicycle, but if it works for you that's what matters.